# Show the limit $\lim_{z\to0} \frac{2|z|^2}{\operatorname{Re}(z^2)}$ does not exist?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers

Complex variables:
How do I prove that $$\lim_{z\to0} \frac{2|z|^2}{\operatorname{Re}(z^2)}$$ does not exist?

I am sorry, I just started learning limits in complex variables, And I am very confused about limits
Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Write $z=x+iy$. Can you express the inner function as a function of $x,y$? Then, you can show that the new limit does not exist when $(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z = x + iy$. If you approach $0$ along the real axis then $z = x$ and the limit is

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2|x|^2}{\Re(x^2)} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x^2}{x^2} = 2  
$$

But if you approach $0$ along the imaginary axis then $z = iy$ and the limit is

$$
\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{2|iy|^2}{\Re[(iy)^2]} = \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{2y^2}{-y^2} = -2  
$$

Since these numbers are different the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Take $z=re^{i \theta}$ (where $r=|z|$)

When $r \longrightarrow 0 $ then $z \longrightarrow0$

If your limit, after this substitution, depends on the values of $\theta$ then does not exist.